# R: Krovak projection in R - identical in ArcGIS, different in R?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, r, cartography

I have two files: shapefile and raster, both in the same coordinate system in ArcGIS: EPSG 5514.

Check information on projection in ArcGIS for **raster**:

```
S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North
WKID: 5514 Authority: EPSG

Projection: Krovak
False_Easting: 0.0
False_Northing: 0.0
Pseudo_Standard_Parallel_1: 78.5
Scale_Factor: 0.9999
Azimuth: 30.28813975277778
Longitude_Of_Center: 24.83333333333333
Latitude_Of_Center: 49.5
X_Scale: -1.0
Y_Scale: 1.0
XY_Plane_Rotation: 90.0
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_S_JTSK
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_S_JTSK
  Spheroid: Bessel_1841
    Semimajor Axis: 6377397.155
    Semiminor Axis: 6356078.962818189
    Inverse Flattening: 299.1528128
```

Check information on projection in ArcGIS for **Shapefile**:

```
S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North
WKID: 5514 Authority: EPSG

Projection: Krovak
False_Easting: 0.0
False_Northing: 0.0
Pseudo_Standard_Parallel_1: 78.5
Scale_Factor: 0.9999
Azimuth: 30.28813975277778
Longitude_Of_Center: 24.83333333333333
Latitude_Of_Center: 49.5
X_Scale: -1.0
Y_Scale: 1.0
XY_Plane_Rotation: 90.0
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_S_JTSK
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_S_JTSK
  Spheroid: Bessel_1841
    Semimajor Axis: 6377397.155
    Semiminor Axis: 6356078.962818189
    Inverse Flattening: 299.1528128
```

**in ArcGIS totally identical coordinate systems.**

---

If I import them in R by

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)

# import raster
r1<-raster("F:/.../r1_2013.img")

#import shp
d.shp <- readOGR(dsn = "F:/.../dummy_data_arcgis_r",
                     layer = "np_by_manag")
```

and I want to check data projection, **there is difference in projection in my PREVIOUSLY IDENTICAL CRS**:

```
> proj4string(r1)    # RASTER
[1] "+proj=krovak +lat_0=24.83333333333333 +lon_0=49.5 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"

> proj4string(d.shp)   # SHAPEFILE
[1] "+proj=krovak +lat_0=49.5 +lon_0=24.83333333333333 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"
>
```

which cause problems in any spatial operation I want to perform further.

**Why R modify my projection?** Is it caused by various nature of my files: shapefile / raster? **How can I get rid of it and which one of Krovak CRS is correct?**

My aim, after finishing this transformations, is to:

1. convert raster r1 to polygon p.r1,
2. intersect polygon p.r1 with d.shp
3. calculate areas of each polygon

---

```
# convert raster to polygon
p.r1<-rasterToPolygons(r1, dissolve = T)

# intersect polygon from raster with another one
int.r <-intersect(p.r1,d.shp)  

# calculate areas (in m2) for every polygon in intersected shp
int.r$area <- sapply(int.r@polygons, function(x) x@Polygons[[1]]@area)
```

My dummy files are attached here: http://ulozto.sk/xKoewAzg/dummy-data-arcgis-r-zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ESRI decided to define their own projection parameters:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Question-about-Krovak-projection-and-ESRI-XY-Plane-Rotation-parameter-td4291471.html

There has also been some discussion on the GDAL list recently:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.gdal.devel/42132

I suspect the raster package is applying some of the extra parameters in the projection, and possibly doing it wrong.

The underlying extents in the data are the same:

```
> extent(r1)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -373118.6 
xmax        : -366218.6 
ymin        : -1176124 
ymax        : -1170154 
> extent(d.shp)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -373118.6 
xmax        : -366212.9 
ymin        : -1176124 
ymax        : -1170145
```

and if you transform the shape back to lat-long you get something in the Czech and Slovakian region:

```
> bbox(spTransform(d.shp,CRS("+init=epsg:4326")))
       min      max
x 19.70567 19.79555
y 49.23434 49.29116
```

EXCEPT that the x and y coordinates are swapped! Prague is about 14N 50E. This appears to be the major problem with this CRS - the coordinates are in the wrong order and one is increasing in a southerly direction.

The projection read in by `raster` is even wronger, when projected to lat-long the coordinates are in completely the wrong place:

```
> extent(projectExtent(r1,"+init=epsg:4326"))
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 44.3646 
xmax        : 44.46467 
ymin        : 49.24811 
ymax        : 49.30581
```

I think if you set the raster projection to the same as the shape, then you can do your spatial overlays etc because nothing will complain about mismatching coordinate systems:

```
> projection(r1) = projection(d.shp)
>
```

But bear in mind that what you plot on the screen is possibly rotated and reflected compared to the ground. However if I load them into QGIS and give them both an EPSG of 5514, then when compared to how R plots them, I get this:

[image]

R on the left, QGIS on the right, where your data appears to be in a forest on the Poland/Slovakia border. QGIS has a definition for EPSG:5514, unlike R. The QGIS map looks the same with EPSG:5514, EPSG:2065 or EPSG:5221, the last two of which I do have in R, so I could assign those to my data. I don't see much difference between them, possibly a tiny survey shift that doesn't materially affect the data.

So the raster is definitely *wrong*. In fact when I do what I should have done at the start and looked at the projection parameters of the file, it *DOESNT* have the same projection parameters as the shape:

```
$ gdalinfo r1_2013.img 
Driver: HFA/Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
Files: r1_2013.img
       r1_2013.img.aux.xml
Size is 230, 199
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North",
    GEOGCS["S_JTSK",
        DATUM["S_JTSK",
            SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128000033],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Krovak"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",24.83333333333333],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",49.5],
    PARAMETER["azimuth",30.28813975277778],
```

Notice it has the central **longitude** at 49 degrees rather than 24.83. How did that happen? Did ArcGIS write the wrong CRS to the image file??

In short, as long as the back-transform to lat-long looks sensible, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I have no idea about what did happen to my projection in ArcGIS, but I am really happy that you have clarified my confusions... thank you @Spacedman ! ;)